# I was learning js in ubuntu but when i give cmd of node index.js it will enter in new line and ignored the fist cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var user = {
    firstName: "vishu",
    courseCount: 10,
    getCourseCount: function () {
        console.log("line 7",this);
        function sayHello(){
            console.log("hello");
            console.log("line 10", this);
        }
        sayHello();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect the command to do? If you want it to run your script, it does. It doesn't show anything simply because your js script doesn't call anything but build an object only.

To make it call your function, try

```
var user = {
    firstName: "vishu",
    courseCount: 10,
    getCourseCount: function () {
        console.log("line 7",this);
        function sayHello(){
            console.log("hello");
            console.log("line 10", this);
        }
        sayHello();
    }
}
user.getCourseCount() // add this line to call the function in your user object
```